Error in my textbook

I think the following is an error in my textbook I thought of mailing the author about this error to the author but since I'm also a high school student I'm not very sure if I'm correct
My textbook says that A is the local maxima and C is the local minima which perfectly matches with the definition in wikipedia

A real-valued function $f$ defined on a real line is said to have a local (or relative) maximum point at the point $x^*$, if there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $f(x^*) \ge f(x)$ whenever $\lvert x − x^*\rvert < \varepsilon$. The value of the function at this point is called maximum of the function. Similarly, a function has a local minimum point at $x^*$, if $f(x^*) \le f(x)$ whenever $\lvert x − x^*\rvert < \varepsilon$. The value of the function at this point is called minimum of the function.

But my textbook also says that "Point B is called a local minimum because in its immediate area it is the lowest point, and so represents the least or minimum value of the function in that area." I don't know why but this line doesnt make sense to me as we can move a bit right to achieve even lower value also it does not satisfy the definition given in wikipedia. Also the exact function is not given only the graph is shown.Am I making some mistake or is the text book wrong?

Can you include a photo of the textbook with that statement? It might be that they are referencing another figure, or that they did use the wrong figure.

No, in the domain pictured, $B$ is neither a maximum nor a minimum. This is an inflection point/saddle point.

The eyes of the author may see the function as being constant in some interval around $B$.

@CalvinLin I've recheck it's correct only

(A) The Image is very clear that $A$ is marked local maxima & $C$ is marked local minima. We can also see that $B$ is not marked like that. So every thing is right till now. In Case the text later says that $B$ is local minima , then it is a typo & OP should change $B$ to $C$. (B) This is a minor issue , @Justauser , we do not know the quality of the text with just this. I have seen worse , much much worse. I do not think we should cast aspersions on that Author just yet !
